# How to update user image (on click) in navbar Angular

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have navbar (code below) After setting *ngIf = "user" I try to display user avatar in the navbar but get that placeholder. After refreshing the page I get user avatar. So I'm wondering how i can refresh only navbar after clicking login button.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
 <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive] = "['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}">
      <a  class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/register']">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="!authService.loggedIn()" class="nav-item"  [routerLinkActive] = "['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}" >
        <a class="nav-link"[routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li *ngIf="authService.loggedIn()" class="nav-item avatar dropdown" style="cursor:pointer">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

        <img *ngIf="user" src="{{user.avatar}}" style="border-radius:15px; height:35px; width:35px;">
         <img *ngIf="!user" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dk34qvajk/image/upload/v1513190129/placeholder.png" style="border-radius:15px; height:35px; width:35px;"> 
      </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right dropdown-purple" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink-5">
          <a  class="dropdown-item waves-effect waves-light" [routerLink]="['/profile']">Profile</a>
          <a  class="dropdown-item waves-effect waves-light" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item waves-effect waves-light" [routerLinkActive] = "['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions] = "{exact:true}" (click)="onLogoutClick()" >Logout</a>
        </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**UPD**

here is navbar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-navbar',
 templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

 user: Object;

  constructor(private authService:AuthService, private router:Router, private flashMessage:FlashMessagesService) { }

//added onInit body to get user object in navbar

ngOnInit() {
   this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile=>{
     this.user = profile.user;
   },
   err=>{
    console.log(err);
    return false;
   });
}

 onLogoutClick(){
   this.authService.logout();
   this.flashMessage.show('You are logged out', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000 });
   this.router.navigate(['/login']);
   return false;
 }
}
```

and now here is auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt'

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  authToken : any;
  user : any;

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  registerUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:17696/signup', user, {headers:headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
  }

  authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:17696/signin', user, {headers:headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
  }

  getProfile(){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken)
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:17696/users/profile', {headers:headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
  }

  storeUserData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));    //cause local storage can store only strings not objects
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user =user;
  }

  loadToken(){
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token; 
  }

  loggedIn(){
    return tokenNotExpired('id_token');
  }

  logout(){
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

Also I've got some errors like [image: this] (cause trying to get profile  on initing navbar component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the async missing.

*ngIf="user | async"

And also you can use the safe navigator operator the '?'

{{user?.avatar}}

Try this and if it doesn't upload your components code to see it better.

Comment: Did you try what told you?

Comment: yes, sure. It does nothing. Just showing avatar after reloading page by F5

Comment: Its odd, I have something very similar and it only worked when I added that. Idk what could be.

Comment: I tried again and you know now its not showing even name of user after reloading page.

Comment: By doing this you are not waiting for the user to be there. The logic you are using to fetch the user is okay. Maybe check if the image path is okay. To do this try hardcoding the path to see if its pointing right.

`<img *ngIf="user" src="{{user.avatar}}" style="border-radius:15px; height:35px; width:35px;">`
         
`<img *ngIf="!user" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dk34qvajk/image/upload/v1513190129/placeholder.png" style="border-radius:15px; height:35px; width:35px;">`

Comment: Here is an example of how im doing it in my code

`<div *ngIf="auth.user | async">
     <button class="btn bg-blue mart1 hovered" (click)="deleteCertification(photo.id)">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
     </button>
    </div>
    <img src="{{photo.url}}" (click)="setModalImage(photo)" class="thumbn hover-shadow cursor"
      data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">`

Answer (score 0):

`

```
<nav ngIf="!Hide" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
seu código
</nav>
```

If you will not change of page when click on login button: set !hide to hide and then to set hide to !hide.

```
hide = true;
hide = false;
```

if you will change of page:

```
location.reload()
```

Comment: how to use location.reload()?

Comment: You have another option: `import {NgZone} from '@angular/core'; and when click on login button use it: `this.ngzone.run(() => {
           });`. this will reload.

Comment: location.reload(). is javascript. it will take the window and reload it.